# Can you work out the number which replaces the question mark?

Tags: mathematics, pattern

[image: 3 boxes] 
The numbers in all the three groups follow the same mathematical pattern. 
Can you work it out?

> Note : The 4 numbers in a square form a single group, and the answer is a positive integer.

Please try first without the hints.

> Hint 1: You have to work on equations involving addition.
>
>
>  Hint 2: You should calculate the powers of each number.

Comment: "there are several possible, and valid, solutions"
This means the question is too broad in my opinion. If you add enough hints so there is only a single valid solution this question might be good enough

Comment: @IvoBeckers If someone uses hints, then there is exactly one mathematically correct solution. I have found 2 correct solutions till now.

Comment: @IvoBeckers, Ok should I narrow it down the question to only one solution ? That would be killing the creativity and fun :-/

Comment: There is a difference between a **hint** which will usually guide people more easily to the correct solution and a **condition** or restraint that reduces the number of valid solutions. The way you have phrased this question, there could be a number of valid solutions. If you wish to add constraints then they need to be part of the main question, not hidden in spoiler tags.

Comment: Perhaps you should give two or more examples instead of only one example. The current example has square(6)+square(8)=square(1+9), that is, square-of-upper-left-number plus square-of-lower-right-number equals square of (upper-right-number plus lower-left-number). And I can come up with tons of other potential solutions.

Comment: @Gamow But in that case, the answer would not be an integer.
Ok, I am adding one more group of numbers, which fits the pattern, to it...

Comment: @GordonK Hope the current hidden hints are ok? Gamow edited them so.

And yes, this is the final update, hope it makes it crystal clear :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is:

> 87

How to find it:

> Label the contents of the square A / B / C / D, with A upper left, B upper right, C lower left and D lower right.

Based on these names for the spots, we find:

> (A³ + D³) = (C³-B³) for all examples.

We now know:

> x³ + 25³ = 90³ - 38³, or x³ = 658503, which solves for x = 87.